# How does Eclipse determine which files to flag as a Match when Searching for a string?

Tags: eclipse

I'm new to Java / Eclipse, and I need to rename a particular field in this application. I did a simple search for the string and while looking through the results, I am puzzled by what I see. Just did a search for "Recipient Type":

[image]

Why does it say "(2 matches)" next to `ClientListReport.jsp` but it doesn't say anything for `DocumentStatusReport.jsp` or `NotificationReport.jsp`? It's *really* tedious having to expand every single result because I need to change those as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is exactly one match in the file you don't get the match count. If there is more than one match you get the count. Files with no matches are not included in the search results.

Comment: I guess that sort of makes sense, but also seems kind of counter intuitive at the same time IMO. Thanks though! :) I thought it was some weird interaction with my search paramters and the non-alpha characters surrounding the string i was looking for.